# Phone app: How to dial a name with non-US characters?

Tags: phone-app

I have a friend called Kåre Østergård. I can search him in contacts using the `å` and the `Ø` characters, but I am not able to find "Kåre" using the [Phone by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer)'s dial pad, that looks something *similar* to the image below.

On previous OnePlus phones using previous android versions, I believe "Kare" would also find "Kåre", but not on my Google Pixel 6.

So how do I dial Kåre Østergård using the stock Android phone dial?

[image: Android phone dial]

Comment: By " stock Android phone dial (on Google Pixel 6)", I'd assume this [Phone by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) app, not another dialer app? Note that vendors can (and some usually) customize their system app, including the dialer app, and thus may behave differently.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it is the [Phone by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) app